# JPA lazy initialization error with @OneToMany @EmbeddedId

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In Sprinboot/JPA I defined an entity with one-to-may association as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "useraccount", catalog = "useraccount")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

//other stuff...
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="tokenId.user", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval =true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<SecureToken> tokens = new HashSet<>();


 public Set<SecureToken> getTokens()
 {
  return this.tokens;
 }
   //other getter and setter   
}
```

The SecureToken entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "secureToken", catalog = "useraccount")
public class SecureToken implements Serializable
{
@EmbeddedId
public SecureTokenId tokenId= new SecureTokenId();

@Column(unique = true)
private String token;

private Timestamp isConsumed;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(updatable = false)
private Timestamp timestamp;

@Column(updatable = false)
@Basic(optional = false)
private Timestamp expireAt;

@MapsId("user_id")
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName ="id")
@ManyToOne    
private UserAccount user;

public SecureToken(UserAccount user, String token, String tokenType, Timestamp timestamp, Timestamp expire)
{
   super();       
   this.token=token;       
   this.tokenId.setTokenType(tokenType);
   this.tokenId.setUser(user);
   this.timestamp=timestamp;
   this.expireAt=expire;      
   this.isExpired=false;        
}
}
```

The SecureTokenId:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class SecureTokenId implements Serializable
 {
  @Column(name="tokenType")
  private String tokenType;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserAccount user;

public SecureTokenId()
{
    super();
}   

public SecureTokenId(String tokenType)
{
    //this.user_id=user_id;
    this.tokenType=tokenType;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{     
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;    
    SecureTokenId that = (SecureTokenId) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.tokenType, that.tokenType) &&
                Objects.equals(this.user.getId(), that.user.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(tokenType, this.user.getId());
}

public void setTokenType(String tokenType)
{
  this.tokenType=tokenType;
}

public String getTokenType()
{
  return this.tokenType;
}


public void setUser(UserAccount user)
{
 this.user=user;
}
        
public UserAccount getUser()
{
  return this.user;
}

public Long getTokenId()
{
  return this.user.getId();
}

    
 }
```

But calling the method getToken() of entity UserAccount gets the famous "LazyInitializationException". I generally use Hibernate.initialize, but with this configuration I cannot get rid of the problem.

This how I create a token within a @Service annoted SecureTokenService class.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public SecureToken generateToken(UserAccount user, String tokenType)
{
  byte[] random = new byte[64];
  new SecureRandom().nextBytes(random);
  Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
  LocalDateTime expire= LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(12);
  SecureToken token = new SecureToken(new SecureTokenId(user, tokenType),Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(random),                                          
                                      timestamp, Timestamp.valueOf(expire));
     
  return token;
}
```

Then in the UserService class (@Service annotated) I try to create a token:

```
  SecureToken token = secureTokenService.generateToken(user, type);       
  secureTokenService.save(token);      
  user.addSecureToken(token); //Error 
  this.save(user)
```

When I try to associate the token with the user the error is thrown. Without that statement, the application seems working but  even with "spring.jpa.open-in-view = false" in application.properties calling user.getTokens() rises the lazy initialization error.

Answer (score 1):

In parent child relationship, you didn't declare any parent reference from child side.

In the parent side (`UserAccount`), you declared as follows

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="user"....
```

Which means your child side (`SecureToken`) there is no such property named `user`.

To get rid of this situation,

First you need to declare `user` inside of `SecureToken` / `SecureTokenId`. From your definition, you declared `user_id` inside `SecureTokenId`, instead declare `user` inside `SecureTokenId`.

```java
...
public class SecureTokenId ... {

    ... 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserAccount user;

    ...
}
```

Then in the `UserAccount` declare the `@OneToMany` as follows

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="tokenId.user"...
private Set<SecureToken> tokens;
```

Comment: I update the code following your guidelines (see the updated question), but i have the same error.

Comment: Remove initialization of the id `public SecureTokenId tokenId= new SecureTokenId();`. Instead of initializing every property of `SecureTokenId`, pass `SecureToken` as constructor parameter.

Comment: public SecureToken(SecureTokenId tokenId, String token, Timestamp timestamp, Timestamp expire)
    {
       super();   
       this.tokenId=tokenId;
       this.token=token;    
       this.timestamp=timestamp;
       this.expireAt=expire;      
       this.isExpired=false;        
    }
But same error.

Comment: Did you remove the initialization `= new SecureTokenId();` ? Please mention where are you calling the `getTokens()` method. Is it outide the class of `@Service` annotated method ? If so are your `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property set to `false` in application properties.

Comment: Yes I did. See the last part of question that I have updated